# How can I use postgresql reverse function with EFCore

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I want to create an SQL query with EFCore like below.

```
FROM "Customers" AS c
            where reverse("Phone") LIKE reverse('%#####');
      ORDER BY 1
      LIMIT @__p_2 OFFSET @__p_1
```

I'm trying do with LINQ but this code is not working and also I couldn't find reverse method inside `EF.Functions`

```
query = query.Where(c => c.Phone.Reverse().ToString() == $"{phone}%");
```

throws an error

> Message": "The LINQ expression 'DbSet\r\n    .Where(c
> => c.Phone\r\n        .Reverse().ToString() == __Format_0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be
> translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a
> call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
> ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
> more information.

Is there any way to create reverse function query with PostgreSQL/Npgsql provider for Entity Framework Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no simple/idiomatic way to express string reversal in .NET; note that `c.Phone.Reverse().ToString()` does *not* return the reversed phone, since it invokes ToString on the IEnumerable returned from Reverse.

I've added EF.Functions.Reverse for the upcoming version 5.0 - see https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/pull/1496.